# How to get TabBarController to animate ViewControllers using Monotouch

Tags: animation, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarController controlling 5 ViewControllers. When a tab is pressed to the right of current I'd like the new ViewController to slide in from the right side. Pressing left of the current tab would have the VC slide in from the left.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS7, `UITabBarController` has 2 properties you can set to control the transitions:

```cs
public Func<UITabBarController, UIViewController, UIViewController, IUIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning> GetAnimationControllerForTransition;
public Func<UITabBarController, IUIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, IUIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning> GetInteractionControllerForAnimationController;
```

Apple documentation for those are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController%3aanimationControllerForTransitionFromViewController%3atoViewController%3a) and [there](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController%3ainteractionControllerForAnimationController%3a).